# Angular 17 Material Table with Signal data source

Tags: angular, angular-material, signals, angular-signals

In an Angular 17 application, is there a way to use signal-based data as a datasource for a material table (mat-table)?

I tried passing it as I would with an array data source

`<table mat-table [dataSource]="store.users()">`

Comment: And what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an example of using signals for rendering a mat table here you go, we can use `.set()` to update the value and angular/material will pickup the changes and update the view!

ts

```
import { Component, WritableSignal, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource: WritableSignal<PeriodicElement[]> = signal([]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.set(ELEMENT_DATA);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      const data = ELEMENT_DATA.map((x) => {
        x.weight = Math.random();
        return x;
      });
      this.dataSource.set(data);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

html

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource()" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/yznykz?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-basic-example.html)